# Composite of continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

I would like some feedback and corrections to the proof below.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous functions at $x_0\in X$. Suppose $f(X)\subset Y$ and that $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous functions at $y_0=f(x_0)$. Show that $h:=g\circ f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function at $x_0 \in X$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

We have that $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$, that is, for all $\varepsilon_f > 0$ there is a $\delta_f > 0$ such that

$$x\in X,\ \left|x-x_0\right| < \delta_f \implies \left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right| < \varepsilon_f$$

We also have that $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $y_0=f(x_0)$, that is, for all$\varepsilon_g > 0$ there is a $\delta_g > 0$ such that

$$y\in Y, \left|y-y_0\right| < \delta_g \implies \left|g(y)-g(y_0)\right| < \varepsilon_g \iff  \left|g(y)-g(f(x_0))\right| < \varepsilon_g$$

As $f(X)\subset Y$ and we've defined a function $h := g\circ f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$, we create a restriction $g|_{f(X)}\colon f(X) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Knowing that every restriction of a continuous function is continuous and that $x_0 \in f(X)$, then $g|_{f(X)}$ is continuous, that is, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$f(x)\in f(X)\subset Y, \left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right| < \delta \implies \left|g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))\right| < \varepsilon$$

Therefore, the function $h$ is continuous at $x_0$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. What you are supposed to prove is *not* that final expression. It is: for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall x\in X):|x-x_0|<\delta\implies\bigl|g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)-g\bigl(f(x_0)\bigr)\bigr|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta'>0$ such that$$(\forall y\in Y):\bigl|y-f(x_0)\bigr|<\delta'\implies\bigl|g(y)-g\bigl(f(x_0)\bigr)\bigr|<\varepsilon$$and take $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall x\in X):|x-x_0|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(x_0)\bigr|<\delta'$$and then $(1)$ will hold.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I thought it was the same because every $x\in X$ will end up in $f(X)$, and as $f(X)\subset Y$ and $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $y=f(x_0)$, this would be enough to construct a restriction and therefore show that $g\circ f$ is continuous.

Comment: oh, ok, I got it! Thanks!